# Как выводить на странице архива постов содержание конкретной страницы?

Tags: wordpress

Я создал тип постов "books" (при помощи плагина Custom Post Types) и верстаю страницу-архив постов этого типа. Я хочу выводить на этой странице листинг всех страниц этого типа, а также разместить дополнительную информацию, которую можно было бы редактировать в админке. Вопрос - как это сделать?

Я создал файл-шаблон archive-books.php для архива страниц нового типа. В коде этого файла я вывожу стандартным циклом WordPress листинг с постами типа "books" - с этим все в порядке. Код примерно такой:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
   while ( have_posts() ) :
      the_post();
        the_title();
и т.д.
```

На этой же странице, помимо листинга, я хочу выводить содержание страницы, которая будет доступа из админки. И я не понимаю как это сделать.

Что я пробовал? Я создал страницу с адресом my-site.ru/books/, а в конце файла archive-books.php вывожу заголовок и содержание страницы:

```
the_title();
the_content();
```

но ни заголовок, ни содержаине этой страницы не выводится после листинга. Понимаю что запутался в исполняемых файлах и логике движка, помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я хочу выводить на этой странице листинг всех страниц этого типа, а
> также разместить дополнительную информацию, которую можно было бы
> редактировать в админке. Вопрос - как это сделать?

Вариант1. Использовать описание. См [term_description](https://wp-kama.ru/function/term_description), [get_the_archive_description](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_archive_description)

В этом случае описание типа контента указывается при регистрации типа записи в параметре description, при написании `register_post_type()`.

Вариант2. В шаблоне создать сайдбар и выводить текст через виджеты.

Вариант3. Создать настройку в админке. См [API настроек](https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html). Можно совместить с первым вариантом.

Вариант4 (костыльный). Использовать произвольное поле одной из записей или даже поля юзера.

Вариант5. Создать обычную страницу в админке с нужным контентом, а листинг записей этого типа выводить шорткодом (есть плагины для этого) или использую шаблон страницы или/и [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Comment: Спасибо. А где в админке редактируется это поле для архива полей, а не для таксономии?

Comment: @Viktor, обновил пост.

Comment: спасибо. То есть моя идея о том, чтобы создать для архива полноценную страницу (которую бы пользователь видел в списке страниц), доступную для редактирования так же, как и остальные страницы - нереализуема получается? 

ПС: странно тогда, что WP позволяет создать страницу с таким же slug-ом, что и зарегестрированная страница архива. Я думал их как-то можно "поженить" все-таки между собой.

Comment: @Viktor добавил 5й вариант. Если ответ помог решить задачу - стоит его отметить. см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers